# How to compile app in C with module?

Tags: c++, c

I want to do application, which can be compiled with external modules, for example like in php. In php you can load modules in runtime, or compile php with modules together, so modules are available without loading in runtime. But i don't understand how this can be done. If i have module in module.c and there is one function, called say_hello, how can i register it to main application, if you understand what i mean?

```
/* module.c */
#include <stdio.h>

// here register say_hello function, but how, if i can't in global scope
// call another function?

void say_hello() 
{
  printf("hello!");
}
```

If i compile all that files(main app + modules) together, there isn't some reference to say_hello function from main app, because it is called only if user call it in its code. So how can i say to my app, hey, there is say_hello function, if someone want to call it, you know it exists.

EDIT1: I need to have something like table at runtime, where i can see if user called function exists (have C equivavent). Header files doesn't help to me.

EDIT2: My app is interpret for my script langugage.

EDIT3: If someone call function in php, php interpret must know that function exists. I know about dynamic linking and if .so or .dll is loaded, then some start routine is called and you can simple register function in that dll, so php interpret can see, if some module registred for example function called "say_hello". But if i want compile php with for example gd support, then how gd functions are registred to some php function list, hashtable or whatever?

Comment: 1. Choose : C or C++, not both. 2. Take your favourite text book 3. Go to the page talking about libraries.

Comment: You need to read about Dynamic Libraries.

Comment: Generally, for C programs you need to define a plugin/module API yourself. E.g. a plugin is a DLL with a function of some predetermined name, that you load using whichever API is right for the platform. (Should be `dlopen()` on POSIX.) This function would then return some sort of dictionary structure that maps names to function pointers, or to structures describing your language's objects.

Comment: Also: take a look at how other scripting languages do this. Python and Lua both have sane extension APIs, the documentation for them should give you some insight into how to structure one.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you are looking for is dynamic libraries (we call runtime loadable modules as dynamic/shared libraries in C and in the OS world, in general). Take, for example, [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) which supports plugins to extend it's functionalities. It gives a particular interface to it's plugin-makers to abide by, say functions to register, load, unload and use, which the plugins will have to follow.

When the program loads, it looks for such dynamic libraries in it's `plugins` directory, if present, it'll load and use it, else it'll skip exposing the functionality. The reason why an interface is needed is that since different modules can have different functionalities which are unknown uptil runtime, an app. has to have a common, agreed-upon way of "talking" to it's plugins/modules.

Every C program can be linked to a static or a dynamic library; static will copy the code from the library to the said program, there by leaving no dependencies for the program to run, while linking to a dynamic library expects the dynamic library to be present when the program is launched. A third way of doing it, is not to link to a DLL, but just asking the OS to perform a load operation of the library. If this succeeds, then the dynamic module is used, else ignored. The functionality which the dynamic library should perform is exposed to the user, only if the load call succeeds.

It is to be noted that this is a operating system provided feature and it has nothing to do with the language used (C or C++ or Python doesn't matter here); as far as C is concered, the compiler still links to known code i.e. code which is available @ compile time. This is the reason for different operating system, one needs to write different code to load a dynamic module. Even more, the file type/format of syuch libraries vary from system to system. In Linux it's called shared objects (.so), in Mac it's called dynamic libraries (.dylib) and in Windows as Dynamic link libraries (.dll).

Comment: Your last paragraph is subtly misleading. Static linking and having a dependency on a library aren't equivalent concepts. You can very much have a hard dependency on a dynamically linked library – most apps work that way. (What is true is that you usually need a DLL when you want to to load code on-demand at runtime. It's just not the only use case.)

Answer (score 1):

C is not interpreted language. So you need linking, you may want static linking or dynamic linking.

Program building consists of 2 major phases: compiling and linking. During compiling all c-files are translated into machine code, leaving called functions unresolved (`obj` or `o` files). Then linker merges all these files into one executable, resolving what was unresolved.

This is static linking. Linked module becomes integral part of executable.

Dynamic linking is platform specific. Under windows these are DLLs. You should issue a system call to load DLL after which you will be able to call functions from it.

Comment: There's nothing about the language that makes it compiled or interpreted, that's completely up to the toolchain.  And in fact C interpreters do exist.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is **dynamic library**. Let's first take a look at the example provided in [the Linux manpage of dlopen(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen):

```
/* Load the math library, and print the cosine of 2.0: */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *handle;
    double (*cosine)(double);
    char *error;

    handle = dlopen("libm.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    dlerror();    /* Clear any existing error */

    /* Writing: cosine = (double (*)(double)) dlsym(handle, "cos");
       would seem more natural, but the C99 standard leaves
       casting from "void *" to a function pointer undefined.
       The assignment used below is a workaround. */

    *(void **) (&cosine) = dlsym(handle, "cos");

    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("%f\n", (*cosine)(2.0));
    dlclose(handle);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

There's also a [C++ dlopen mini HOWTO](http://www.isotton.com/devel/docs/C++-dlopen-mini-HOWTO/C++-dlopen-mini-HOWTO.html).

For more general information about dynamic loading, start from [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) first.

Comment: I know about this, but this is used when you have dynamically loaded module. I want to compile module with my app, so there is native support of that module. In php you compile --with gd support for example and then you don't need load gd dinamically, but how php is informed about functions in gd module?? That is what i am intereseting.

Comment: @Krab I don't think the GD extension is statically compiled with PHP itself in this way. I believe `--with` just let PHP know the existence of the GD extension and its functions. It also has to load the `gd.so` in run time. For how this works, see http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/

Answer (score -5):

I think it is impossible, if i understand what you mean. Because it is compiled language.

Comment: He needs dynamic linked libraries. -1

Comment: -1: This makes no sense. All interpreted languages are implemented using C, so it's possible to do what the OP wants a runtime, just not as a first class language feature.